# CUDA JIT compile from device

Tags: cuda

Is it possible to JIT compile CUDA code from the device? The documentation says that a part of the runtime is supported on the device. Does that mean the driver APIs can't be called?

Comment: No and Yes, in that order...

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to JIT compile CUDA code from the device?

No, it's not possible.  CUDA Dynamic Parallelism only supports [aspects of the runtime API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#api-reference) not the driver API.

> Does that mean the driver APIs can't be called?

That is correct.  You cannot use the driver API in device code.